# About weak convergence in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, dual-spaces

doing my homework I'm dealing with this:

Let, for all $n\in \mathbb{N} \quad f_n(t) := e^{-nt^2}, \quad t \in [-1,1]$ Show that

1)$f_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} 0$ in $L^\infty(-1,1)$

2)$f_n$ does not converge weakly to $0$ in $L^\infty (-1,1)$

So I did 1) simply considering
\begin{equation}
|f_n(x)g(x)| \le|g(x)| \quad \forall g \in L^1(-1,1)
\end{equation}

So the result follows easily from the dominated convergence theorem.

But for 2) I know that given $f_n, f \in X^*$ 
\begin{equation}
f_n \rightharpoonup f \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \phi(f_n)\rightarrow \phi(f) \quad \forall \phi \in X^{**}
\end{equation}
But how can I identify the dual of $L^\infty$ to solve this?

Comment: You do not need to identify the dual of $L^\infty$ (which is very complicated).  You only need to construct one element $\phi$ of $L^\infty$ such that $\phi(f_n)\rightarrow \phi(f)$ fails.  A hint for constructing continuous linear functionals:  choose a Banach subspace $E \subset L^\infty$ that contains all the $f_n$, use a continuous functional on $E$, then cite the Hahn-Banach theorem to extend it to all of $L^\infty$.

Comment: but following your reasonment, shouldn't $\phi$ be in $(L^{\infty})^{*}$? Why you say that $\phi$ is in $L^\infty$? Assuming the definition I've written is right..

Comment: Correct, it should say $\phi$ is in $(L^\infty)^*$.

Comment: you mean the definition I've written is wrong? Just to understand

Comment: Your definition is correct, where $X^*$ is $L^\infty$.  My correction is now corrected.

Comment: Ok I got it.. so I should construct one element of $(L^\infty)^*$ It sounds not easy :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I think I solved this.

In this case, we don't have weak convergence of $f_n$ to $0$ because we can consider the extension of Dirac $\delta_0$ as linear functional of $(L^\infty (-1,1))^*$, which is a linear bounded functional on $C[-1,1]$:
\begin{equation}
\delta_0(f) = f(0) \quad \forall f \in C[-1,1]
\end{equation}

Then if we call $T$ this extension it follows $T(f_n) = f_n(0)=1$.

(we have the extension because of Hahn Banach Theorem, thanks for your suggestions).